# How can I capture STDOUT of a docker container to a file OUTSIDE of that container?

Tags: docker

I have a docker container that when I run it, it automatically stops (because of the application crashing) and I cannot figure out why it is crashing because I have found no way to capture the STDOUT of the docker application to a file on the host file system. Without this, when my app crashes, my docker container shuts down and is removed automatically, so there is no container to attach to or get logs from.

I have found no help in the docker documentation for how to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the `docker logs` ?

Comment: You can capture the output of a container to a file just like any other command: `docker run my/image > log.txt 2>&1`. Just don't run it in the background (`-d`).

Comment: If you redirect into a file in the container's file system, use volume mounts to have it in the host's file system.

Comment: @larsks The problem is that my container has to run in the background.

Comment: @thebusybee I wanted to avoid a heavy handed solution like volume mounts inside the container.

Comment: @Paolo The issue with docker logs for me is that our pipeline was running the docker container with -rm because of reasons. So there is no log to inspect since the container gets removed. I have updated our pipeline so that no longer occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a multitude of possibilities for this, some of them mentioned in the comments.

For me, doing redirects or even mounting volumes for the sake of logging is somewhat out of the docker scope. Instead, using a logdriver and checking the logs on the host or central log system seems to be the right approach.

This can be done in a pretty easy way. Let's assume you want to run a simple nginx container.

```
docker run -dt --name web01 -p 8080:80 docker.io/library/nginx:latest
```

This will do the logging as stated from your post (STDOUT of the container), which can be checked via `docker logs`.

If you want to have the log somewhere else, you run something like:

```
docker run -dt --name web01 --log-driver journald -p 8080:80 docker.io/library/nginx:latest
```

Which will produce log entries in journald.

I am not entirely sure how you want to get your hands on the logs, but all options are documented, very well.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/

You can even change the default logdriver (for all containers), if this is your desired behaviour.